# Get the count of different columns of result set

Tags: java

After running the query(DB2), the result set has 4 columns.

```
res1=resultset.getString(Em);  
res2=resultset.getString(Posc);  
res3=resultset.getString(Cal);  
res4=resultset.getString(Ern);
```

The output looks like below:

```
Em     Posc   Cal Ern  
305      1     2   N  
306      1     2   N  
307      2     3   Y
```

- All `Em` are unique
- `Posc` can be any integer
- `Cal` can be any integer
- `Ern` can be N or Y

How can I code to get the count of different values of `Posc` ,`Cal` and `Ern` .

**For eg.** How can I  get the count of all the 1's,2's and so on whatever may be the value of `Posc`.

Similarly how can I get the count of other columns.

Comment: Do you want to change your Java code or do you want a SQL query that returns that information?

Comment: i have the sql query. I want java code that could fetch me the result

Comment: you need sum of all elements in column or rows count? or maybe columns count?

Comment: i need count of different elements in each column.

Comment: ok. then take a look at my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Map<Integer,Integer>` of the value of the column as the key and a count as the value.

For each value of `Posc` you get check if the map contains the value as a key. If not add it with a value of 1. If it does increment the count value

For `Posc` example (I'm assuming that you are looping the result set anyway...)

```
Map<Integer,Integer> countsOfPoscValues = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>

//Result set loop
{
    //Get values
    Integer posc = //....
    if(countsOfPoscValues.containsKey(posc))
    {
         countsOfPoscValues.put(posc, countsOfPoscValues.get(posc)+1);
    }
    else
         countsOfPoscValues.put(posc, 1);
    //....etc
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
        Map<Integer,Integer> emCount = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer,Integer> poscCount = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String,Integer> calCount = new HashMap<>();

        while (resultset.next()) {
            final int em = resultset.getInt(Em);
            final int posc = resultset.getInt(Posc);
            final String cal = resultset.getString(Cal);

            emCount = putKeyValue(emCount,em);
            poscCount = putKeyValue(poscCount ,em);
            calCount = putKeyValue(calCount ,em);
        }

public Map<Object, Integer> putKeyValue(Map<Object, Integer> colCount, Object val) {
    if (colCount.containsKey(val)) {
        colCount.put(val, colCount.get(val).intValue() + 1);
    } else {
        colCount.put(val, 1);
    }

    return colCount;
}
```